# Kickstarter and 2D smartphone games

Tags: game-industry, project-management, console, pc, fund-raising

I am about to launch a Kickstarter project as, after 14 months of full time development on my first iOS game, I run out of money. I developed an iOS game that needs few more months to be ready (the game structure is there but haven't yet worked on balancing the difficulty of the various levels).

**I have a feeling that most of the computer games founded on Kickstarter are for console, PC or Mac and not for smartphones**. The category that many people seem to like is RPG style games.

I have done tons of work over a year and collaborated with musicians and illustrators to get top quality graphics and music. The game looks cool to be an iOS 2D game but, compared to what I've seen on Kickstarter, I feel so little and humbled.

I have searched for smartphone game projects on Kickstarter but haven't found many. I believe that the reason is that people are not keen in backing an APP that is normally sold for 0.99$ **as they perceive is not something big**. Am I the only one having this feeling?

Could anyone please share a list of references to some successfully backed kickstarter smartphone game projects? (In this way the question will not become a "chat" and will fulfill the requirements to be a gamedev question).

Any other article or authoritative answer will be welcome.

Comment: Can you tell us what you're hoping to get from this to help people with their answers? How does the list of successful kickstarter smartphone projects help you?

Comment: It will help me to understand if there are any smartphone game project that get funded 20.000$ or more. Also would be useful for me to try analyze the videos of those projects and see if there are any patterns. I am also interested in trying to read the project updates/comments and see what are the category of user backing those projects. More simply, I am just worried that a smartphone 2D game will not attract backers and was trying to have an idea of the likelihood that a 2D smartphone game project gets funded 20.000$ or more.

Comment: PS: I understand that might not be an appropriate question (I can - and am also searching on Kickstarter.com which is what I have to do but maybe I am missing out something relevant). If you suggest to delete it I will do it.

Comment: I'm just trying to find a way to make it more answerable than people just posting links to kickstarter pages. What else can people add to their answers? It's kind of a polling type question in that way.

Comment: Those things you want to do with the project links - analysing videos, finding patterns, understanding backers - would be better as answers. I think it will be very useful to have answers that went into the elements of a successful smartphone game kickstarter, with references or drawing from experience.

Comment: @Byte56 thanks for your comment. Probably the comment from Cong Xu is a good suggestion for a good answer structure "I think it will be very useful to have answers that went into the elements of a successful smartphone game kickstarter, with references or drawing from experience"

Comment: Sounds good to me. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Kickstarter allows you to search for "Recently successfuly funded", then you just need to through them and search for mobiles. Shamelessly promoting my own question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/55956/crowdfunding-an-indie-game-what-should-i-offer-back

Comment: @sm4 thanks, I had found your question and it is not really the same as mine. You ask "what should I offer back", I ask "what are the characteristics of successfull 2d smartphone game projects". In recently founded projects there are not many 2D smartphone games and, similarly, searching by category is not easy to find good examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some research on this topic before and I agree, there are not many crowdfunding projects for mobile games.

Searching Kickstarter itself is not easy. But it can be done and some people make their living by doing exactly this. What you need to look for are mobile gaming blogs and webzines that crawl through kickstarter and post articles named like: [Top 10 most exciting iPhone and Android games on Kickstarter](http://www.pocketgamer.co.uk/r/Multiformat/Top+10+iPhone+charts/feature.asp?c=40163) or tagged with [kickstarter](http://gamewoof.com/tag/kickstarter/). Second page of Google usually has better results, because the first one is all about kickstarter itself. Also tags and categories on kickstarter homepage can be useful, but as you already said in comments - it is not easy.

When you start looking for the games, soon you will notice a pattern. Most of the really successful games are multiplatform, meant for PCs too. Very successful projects usually include reboots and remakes of geeky games from the past.  I concluded this is due to the demographics of gaming kickstarter benefactors - people who are real enthusiasts, regular gamers and people who really liked games in the past and now have enough money to get to play the games they want. [Typical kickstarter visitor is a male 25-34 years old with no children, at least colledge degree and above average income](https://www.quantcast.com/kickstarter.com/demographics) - this is of course kickstarter on average, not just gaming.

[Smartphone gamer demographics are very different from those of regular games...](http://www.trademob.com/females-mobile-are-reshaping-traditional-gaming-demographics/) I don't think many casual gamers are interested in crowdfunding a game, when they have plethora of simple and entertaining games (for free) in App Store/Play Store.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have recorded and edited a video yesterday keeping those things in mind. It could work. I am only worried about one thing. The game I am developing is using Open GL 2.0 ES and Gyroscope, hence I said in the video that the target for now is only latest generation iOS devices, specifying the technical requirements. In fact I realize only today that the only requirement is having a device with OpenGL 2.0 ES as Gyroscope input can be substituted with a virtual joystic. Will this be likely to mine the success on my fund request?I could write this in the video description

Comment: @mm24 This would be just speculations and I honestly don't know. If you post it as separate question, it will probably get closed as a bad subjective. You can try moving the problem to chat, even though the audience there is much smaller: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development

I'd say: Be honest with people who want to support your effort. If you can make another video, do it. It's just one day delay. In fact make it a feature - gyroscope AND/OR virtual joystick. Some people don't like gyroscope controls!